# How do I get JSON and push it into HTML with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, template-engine

I have HTML pages and I have decided to populate them using JSON generated from an API (api.example.com).

The thing is that I have never used jQuery. What are the basics to pull the information using jQuery and then to fill the HTML with that JSON data, like name, surname, messages?

Should I put the JavaScript codes athe end of the HTML pages (right before )?

Or, is there easy way?

Comment: To me, the "easy way" is to use Knockout. However, whichever template/view engine you use, should be able to support binding to a [complex] model - remember that *JSON is just text, but the corresponding JavaScript object is just a JavaScript object*. (jQuery will automatically do the conversion if the datatype is correctly specified. If you put the "JSON in the HTML" then you're really putting a normal JavaScript Object Literal in the page source..)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I have liked the `data-bind` thing in the [Knockout](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro). It is the right way, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Really depends on what the json looks likes comming back.

First Get your data using ajax.

```
var incomingData; //Incoming Data Variable

$.ajax("http://yourURL.goes.here", {
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    incomingData = data;
  },
  error: function(req, status, err) {
    //console.error("Something went wrong! Status: %s (%s)", status, err);
  }
});
```

Now you will have your data in the `incomingData` variable.

I'd console.log the data, so you can view it, but accessing the parts would be done through DOT notation:

```
incomingData.name;
incomingData.phone;
```

Usually you'll get an array of objects when you return JSON, so you may need to loop through.

```
for(var i = 0; i < incomingData.length; i++) {
    console.log(incomingData[i]);
    $('.yourClass').append(incomingData[i].name + '<br />');
}
```

The above will take the value of the 'name' property and append it to your `<div class="yourclass"></div>` in your html. It will also console log that object your iterating through in the console so you should be able to see all of its properties. Confusing at first, but a necessary JS skill. :)

As far as where to put it your code, best practices is before the closing body tag. Make sure your code is running after jquery has been loaded. Make a main.js file and include it right before your body closing tag:

```
<body>
    ...
    All of your HTML
    ...
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="yourfile.js"></script>
</body>
```